# XML Soap request to crm ondemand from objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, soap, authentication

I m sending an xml soap request to login in my crm ondemand site but i m getting an error "http request did not contain well-formed xml. an attempt to parse it produced an following error something XML-20108 (Fatal Error) start of root element missing". i dont knw what to do :S ... i have wasted my 2 days in it n could not get any progress .. please help me out for this!:( .. there is something wrong in soap request.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:          
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?> \
< soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ \"              xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:enc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:ns9060=\"http://tempuri.org\"> \
< soap:Header> \
< wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand=\"1\"> \
< wsse:UsernameToken> \
< wsse:Username>MyUserName</wsse:Username> \
< wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">MyPassword</wsse:Password> \
< /wsse:UsernameToken> \
< /wsse:Security> \
< /soap:Header> \
< soap:Body> \
< AccountQueryPage_Input xmlns=\"urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/10/2004\"> \
< ListOfAccount xmlns=\"urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Query\"> \
< Account> \
   < AccountName/> \
< /Account> \
< /ListOfAccount> \
< /AccountQueryPage_Input> \
< /soap:Body> \
< /soap:Envelope>"];

 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://secure-ausomxdsa.crmondemand.com/Services/Integration"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [theRequest setValue:@"document/urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/10/2004:AccountQueryPage" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
  [theRequest setValue:@"application/soap+xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
  [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];      


      NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection)
    {
        status.text = @"Connection";
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    }

    - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
     {
         status.text = @"didReceiveResponse";
         [webData setLength: 0];
     }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
     {

          status.text = @"didReceiveData";
          [webData appendData:data];
   }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
        status.text = @"didFailWithError";        
        [connection release];
       [webData release];
   }
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

         NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         status.text = nil;
         status.text = loginStatus;
         [loginStatus release];

         [connection release];
         [webData release];
   } 

  @end
```

Comment: Dude, do yourself a favor and use ASIHTTPRequest: http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fallseeing-i.com%2FASIHTTPRequest%2F&ei=2-VHTa_jLMmXcdSx5OIC&usg=AFQjCNFpUZprrMAY9mTk0aGzEzwSG8L9sg

Comment: dude .. can you tell me whats wrong in my code .. i m new to objective c n wasted 2,3 days in it a very new approach is not a good thing for me :S :(

Comment: For future debugging, use a tool like https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/ to check what your code is actually sending to the server. And a cleaner alternative to hardcoding the XML is to include an XML file as a resouce in your project, and simply load it as NSData before you send.

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be at least two problems with the soap request.

First, the element tags have a space after the `<`.
For example, `< soap:Envelope` should be `<soap:Envelope`.
Remove the leading space in all the starting and closing tags.

Second, the uri for `xmlns:soap` has a trailing space before the closing quote:

```
xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ \"
                                                      ^trailing space
```

There should be no trailing space before the closing quote.

You can validate your xml using something like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp.

This doesn't guarantee the request will work after these fixes but it will rule out invalid xml and hopefully let you move further.